# How to return back when using MS Visio hyperlink to a page within the drawing

Tags: hyperlink, navigation, visio

I am trying to document a flow. I am using the all too familiar option of assigning a hyperlink to a subprocess box.
When one Ctrl + left clicks the shape, Visio navigates to the page. Let us say that the shape is in foo, the link is to page bar.
 Visio navigated me to page bar. Is there a way to navigate back to page foo, akin to the "back" button in a web browser?
I.e., without having to remember that I was reading page foo. Looking at the web did not suggest that one can, or that one can't, rather that this is an unanswered question.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing built into Visio for this purpose, that I know of.

You could build a simple form that would accomplish navigation; it would have back and forward buttons, and the form could just watch the Application object for window page changes.  Every time the page changes, just log that.  Then when you hit the back button, step back through the log.

Answer (score 1):

In Visio 2010, and probably other versions as well, the functionality exists but is not exposed in the GUI by default.  Here's how to add a **Back** button to the Quick Access toolbar:

1. Right-click the ribbon and select "Customize Quick Access Toolbar"
2. Select "All commands" in the dropdown on the left
3. Locate the Back item (it's the green circle with the white left arrow)
4. Double-click it to move it to the right

Comment: Thanks.
Should that work if I publish this on sharepoint, and others access it (read-only) using IE10?

Comment: Not 100% sure but I think on Sharepoint you should be able to use the regular Back functionality of IE.

Answer (score 0):

ALT + Left Arrow
This works in Visio 2010, which I am using.