# Keep track of traversed path when navigating through MS Visio pages

Tags: visio

In a Visio project, I need to keep track of the traversed path (previously accessed pages) when navigating, usually via hyperlinks, through the project pages. This knowledge is needed in order to properly implement a "back" functionality.

Example that requires this path knowledge: (`-->` refers to hyperlink linking)

```
Page1_shape --> Page2
Page3_shape --> Page2
```

Once I am on `Page2`, I want to be able to go back to `Page1` or `Page3` based on where the link originated.

This "back" functionality should be available on presentation mode (i.e., not using the back icon from the Quick Access Toolbar or the Alt + Left shortcut, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33756345/how-to-return-back-when-using-ms-visio-hyperlink-to-a-page-within-the-drawing) -- Those are not available on presentation mode). It should also be available on Visio Online (e.g., when opening and viewing the project on MS Teams).

My understanding is that this is not offered off the shelf (using Visio 2013). If Macros can be used for this functionality, please guide me with some example code snippet.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to return back when using MS Visio hyperlink to a page within the drawing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33756345/how-to-return-back-when-using-ms-visio-hyperlink-to-a-page-within-the-drawing)

Comment: I edited the question to indicate why it is not a duplicate of the above-mentioned question. Briefly, I need the "back" navigation functionality to be available on presentation mode and also while viewing the project on Visio Online (e.g., on MS Teams).

Comment: If no one can think of a solution to that problem, can you think of some utility that offers flow chart creation with this type of back navigation?